# ¿Como puedo organizar a la vez por dos parámetros con sort en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código:

```
bool Organizar(node nodo1, node nodo2){

    return (nodo1.getF() < nodo2.getF());
}

void expandir_nodo(node nodo){


    if (isGoal(nodo)){

        haveSol = true;
    }

    else{

        generateIzquierda(nodo);
        generateDerecha(nodo);

        sort(abiertos.begin(),abiertos.end(),Organizar);
    }

    nodos_expandidos++;
}
```

Tengo todo preparado para organizar el vector "abiertos" por "f" pero hay un parámetro más dentro del objeto "node" por el que me gustaría organizar el vector. Me gustaría ordenar la lista por los objetos que tengan menor f (nodo.getF()) y a demás, entre ellos, que tengan menor h (nodo.getH).

¿A alguien se le ocurre como? Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Buenas. Siempre puedes establecer con una OR la condición de igualdad y seleccionar por el segundo parámetro. Algo como x<y || (x==y&&a<b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues hacer una pequeña modificación a tu función `Organizar( )`:

```
bool Organizar( node nodo1, node nodo2 ) {
  if( nodo1.getF( ) == nodo2.getF( ) )
    return nodo1.getH( ) < nodo2.getH( );

  return nodo1.getF( ) < nodo2.getF( );
}
```

Pero ... si nos fijamos un poco, tu función **debería** ser así:

```
bool Organizar( const node &nodo1, const node &nodo2 ) {
  if( nodo1.getF( ) == nodo2.getF( ) )
    return nodo1.getH( ) < nodo2.getH( );

  return nodo1.getF( ) < nodo2.getF( );
}
```

Con lo que evitaremos copias innecesarias de objetos, ganando en velocidad y seguridad ( al usar `const` ).

Comment: Lo he intentado anteriormente con otras funciones, pero cuando añado "const" no me deja llamar a las funciones miembro de la clase. Por lo tanto no puedo hacer "get" alguno.

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez jejeje ... porque tienes que declarar todas las `getX( )` como `const`, tanto en la declaración de la clase como en la implementación; es largo para un comentario; ¿ Una pregunta con alguno de los intentos que has realizado ?

Comment: Perfecto jajaja. Ninguna pregunta más. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes aprovechar que las tuplas incorporan [comparación lexicográfica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico):

```
bool Organizar(node nodo1, node nodo2){
    return std::tie(nodo1.getF(), nodo1.getH()) , std::tie(nodo2.getF(), nodo2.getH());
}
```

Para usar [`std::tie`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) deberás añadir la cabecera [`<tuple>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple).

Comment: Me da este fallo cuando intento poner esa linea.

"main.cpp:301:51: error: no matching function for call to 'tie'
    return std::tie(nodo1.getF(), nodo1.getH()) , std::tie(nodo2.getF(), nodo2.getH());"

Comment: también habría funcionado con el operador de comparación `==`, que genera un código más legible

Comment: @AlfonsoRodríguez `std::tie` debería estar disponible al incluir la cabecera `<tuple>` a no ser que estés usando un compilador que no de soporte al estándar C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución también puede ser prescindir de la función "Organizar" y sobrecargar el `operator <` para que lo use directamente `std::sort`.

Como función libre podría implementarse:

```
bool operator<(const node& n1, const node& n2)
{
    return n1.getF() == n2.getF() ?
        n1.getH() < n2.getH() :
        n1.getF() < n2.getF();
}
```

De este modo podría ponerse simplemente:

```
sort(abiertos.begin(),abiertos.end());
```